# How to plot the solutions of the equation $f_{a,b}(x)=0$ for $x$ as $a$ and $b$ range through the whole interval $(-2,2)$?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions, multivalued

I have a three-variable function $f_{a,b}(x)$ for $x>0$, and $-2<a,b<2$, say

```
f[x_,a_,b_]:=b^3 Sin[x] + Cos[a/b]
```

**Question**

1. I want to plot the roots of this function for $x>0$ (i.e. the solutions of the equation $f_{a,b}(x)=0$) as the other two parameters range through $-2<a,b<2$; I guess the result should be several continuous lines
2. If this is possible, then, I would like to show them, say, at the vertical line $4$ as in the given picture.

[image]

Comment: What does the horizontal axis represent in  your figure?

Comment: @JimB Nothing. I just need to plot those domains of $x$ which belong to the solutions of the equation when the other two parameters change through the given intervals (the whole range).

Comment: I've heard of the Axis of Evil but hadn't heard about the Axis of Nothing.

Comment: You can ignore the horizontal axis (I just wanted to place the result on a specific line); the problem has only one variable $x$; showing the allowed domain of $x$. @JimB

Comment: If you can determine the roots as functions of `a` and `b`, you can plot them with `Plot3D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since this equation can be solved  directly, we need not use `ContourPlot3D`.

```
sol = Solve[f[x, a, b] == 0, x]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Table[x /. sol /. C[1] -> c, {c, Range[-2, 2]}] // 
  Evaluate, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["a", Blue, Bold, 15], Style["b", Blue, Bold, 15],
    Style["x", Red, 15]}]
```

[image]

- Test the case when `C[1]->0` but still have warning message.

```
FunctionRange[{-ArcSin[Cos[a/b]/b^3], -2 <= a <= 2, -2 <= b <= 2}, {a,
   b}, x, Method -> {"Reduced" -> True}]
```

[image]

- If we ignore `-2<a<2, -2<b<2`,

```
result = 
  Table[FunctionRange[{sol[[1]] /. C[1] -> c}, {a, b}, x], {c, 
    Range[-5, 5]}];
reg = ImplicitRegion[Or @@ result, {x}];
Region[reg]
```

[image]

- Test by `FindInstance` and plot it.

```
NumberLinePlot[
 x /. FindInstance[{b^3 Sin[x] + Cos[a/b] == 0, -2 < a < 2, -2 < b < 
     2}, {a, b, x}, Reals, 200]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I did not mean this, I meant something like the given picture in my question, without the details of changing $a$ and $b$; only showing the intervals of $x$. In other words, in your picture, showing only those parts in the $x$ axis (as continuous lines or points) which collect the given result for $a,b$.  @cvgmt

Comment: Also, if possible, I want to do this without solving the equation; since I need to do this for very large equations which can not be solved exactly.    @cvgmt

Comment: However, as I check your plot, I see that for this particular function, $x$ covers the whole range. @cvgmt

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but $c[1]$ has $\pm2\pi m$ as well, so, does not it cover the whole axis? Anyhow, in general, is it possible to plot the given result (without obtaining explicit solutions) as my picture? @cvgmt