# Is there an alternative way to obtain the given plot directly from the equation $f(a,b,x)=0$?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics, conditional

I have the equation $f(a,b,x)=0$ where the function $f(a,b,x)$ is as follows

```
f[a_, b_, x_] := (x^2 + 2) (Sin[5 a] + Sin[3 b]) - 3 (x^2 + 1) Sin[x]
```

I want to plot the solutions of $0<x<15$ in the equation $f(a,b,x)=0$ as the other two parameters change through the range $-2<\{a,b\}<2$ (more precisely if we have a 3D plot of the solutions, then, to show ONLY the allowed domains of $x$ as continuous lines). In this case, since the equation is simple, I can easily rewrite the equation $f(a,b,x)=0$ as
$$   \sin (5 a)+\sin (3 b)=\frac{3 \left(x^2+1\right) \sin (x)}{x^2+2} ,  $$

and from that, since the function $-2<\sin (5 a)+\sin (3 b)<2$, I use this code

```
Plot[ If[ -2 < (3 (x^2 + 1) Sin[x])/(x^2 + 2) < 2 , 1 ], {x, 0, 15},PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {"x",""}]
```

and it gives me the desired plot for the solutions of $x$ as

[image]

**Question**:

> Is there an alternative way to obtain the given plot **directly** from the equation $f(a,b,x)=0$ **without manipulating and simplifying the equation**? Since I have to do this for very large and complicated functions for $f(a,b,x)$ which there is no hope for simplification.

Comment: May I ask the reason for closing? What is wrong with the question?

Comment: This question is closely related to your earlier question, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/273416/1063, which should be referenced in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `ContourPlot3D`?

Try

```
pic=ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + 2) (Sin[5 a] + Sin[3 b]) - 3 (x^2 + 1) Sin[x]==0, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Based on our discussion (see comments) a numerical solution might be obtained as follows:

Take the x-values from points of ContourPlot3D and map  to value `1`

```
Map[{#, 1} &, pic [[1, 1]][[1]][[All, 3]]] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, it does not help me. I need a plot as I have given in the question.

Comment: @charmin You are asking for the solution `x>0` of the equation `f[x,a,b]==0` and that's what you see in my answer. Your "desired plot" should be clarified in detail, especially the dependency `a,b`!

Comment: I have clearly asked (both in the title and in the text) for an alternative way to obtain my given plot. I knew to use ContourPlot3D but it does not help me. I want to see only the solutions for $x$.

Comment: More precisely, in your plot3D, is it possible to show ONLY the allowed domains of $x$ on a line that should be the same as in my plot?

Comment: @charmin The answer to your question doesn't depend on parameters `a,b`, that's a liittle bit strange to understand. The answer to the reduced question is `Plot[1, {x, 0, 15}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[x, -2 < (3 (x^2 + 1) Sin[x])/(x^2 + 2) < 2] ]`

Comment: Maybe in general you are right since as I have written in the text, in this simple case,  $a$ and $b$ are involved in the sine functions and we can find the max and min of the function $\sin (5a)+\sin (3b)$ but indeed $a$ and $b$ play the role in the solutions for $x$. That is why I have asked the question if the function is not that simple, how can I plot ONLY the allowed solutions for $x$ assuming that $a$ and $b$ change the whole range $(-2,2)$. I thought maybe there is a way by making assumptions or so on.

Comment: let me ask my question again: do you have any idea to show the allowed domains of x (in your 3D plot) as continuous lines?

Comment: A numerical discrete approach might be projection of the points `{a,b,x}` from ContourPlot3D on the x-axis. Clustering give the intervals you're looking for(hopefully)

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I am happy that finally, with my poor English, I could mean what I meant :)

Comment: Still I am a bit worried if this method applies to my other complicated functions (I can say that the function's length is like 4-6 pages when you scroll in Mathematica); I hope ContourPlot3D does not fail in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

We project the set
`{a,b,x},f[a,b,x]==0,-2<a<2,-2<b<2` to a-x plane,and then use `ViewPoint` to only view the range of `x`.

```
plot = ContourPlot3D[f[a,b,x] == 0, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}, {x, -10, 10}];
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[plot[[1]], ScalingTransform[0, {0, 1, 0}]], 
 ViewPoint -> Left, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for the answer. @cvgmt